# I'm deve I want to connect my flask application to the sqlite through sql_alchemy but while running it through the python interpretor it shows error

Tags: sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm creating a web page using the flask now i want to connect it to the sqlite using `sql_alchemy` but while I'm running it using python interpreter it shows an error.

I have installed flask and sql_alchemy using the following commands.

```
pip install flask
pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy
pip install flask_sqlalchemy
```

the error it showing is

```
Python 3.12.1 (tags/v3.12.1:2305ca5, Dec  7 2023, 22:03:25) [MSC v.1937 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pushup_logger import db,create_app
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "S:\dj and f\pushup_logger\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>  
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'
```